# Cannot upload to S3 using CDN Sync Tool

Tags: customization, cdn

I'm trying to synchronise my files with the Amazon S3 server for distribution using CloudFront, as the CDN.

I am currently having troubles syncing the files though.

I've verified that the details are correct, though, when I click on sync it says it is syncing 1 item of many, but looking at the S3 bucket, it doesn't seem to do that.

There are no errors in the PHP log to help me either.

I'm running WordPress 3.1.2, on Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5 - PHP 5.3.6. cURL is installed, as per [PHPInfo](http://service.radonsystems.net/info.php)

Any ideas what's going on here?

Thanks,
Shamil

Comment: Did you even have WP_DEBUG on? Or think of using the contact form in the plugin to ask the author for support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to W3 Total Cache, and it now works.